# Looping through JSON objects and converting them to React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I have a `JSON` file with 3 different objects inside of them (card1, card2 and card3).
I want to loop through these objects in `JavaScript`, turn them into an `array` of objects, then in my React code, I'm trying to turn them into Components depending on how many there are in the JSON file.

What I have so far:

```
import Card from "./card-elements/Card";
import json from "./data.json";

const list = [];
for (const key in json) {
    if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        list.push(key);
    }
}

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="card-area">
            {list.map(i => {
                return <Card title={i.title}
                             description={i.description}
                             borderColor={"red"}/>
            })}
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

data.json:

```
{
    "card1": {
      "title": "Card One",
      "description": "This is card one's description. Straight from JSON file!"
    },
    "card2": {
      "title": "Card Two",
      "description": "Directly from the JSON file, this is card two's description"
    },
    "card3": {
      "title": "Card Three",
      "description": "And finally, this is the last cards description!"
    }
}
```

Current output:
No errors occur with my React, it just only displays one Component and the "title" and "description" are not showing

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to push each item to a `list` and use it. Instead of use `Object.entries`.

Try like this

```
function App() {
    return (
        <div className="card-area">
            {(Object.entries(json) || []).map(([key, value]) => {
                return (
                    <Card
                        title={value.title}
                        description={value.description}
                        borderColor={"red"}
                    />
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In React, you should to use the useState hook to update a component.

```
Try something like:

import Card from "./card-elements/Card";
import json from "./data.json";


function App() {
    const [cardData, setCardData] = React.useState();

    React.useEffect(() => {
      const list = [];
      for (const key in json) {
       if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          list.push(key);
       }
      }
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="card-area">
            {cardData && list.map(i => {
                return <Card title={i.title}
                             description={i.description}
                             borderColor={"red"}/>
            })}
        </div>
    );
}
```

export default App;